# Split a large string (article page) into array (pages) with PHP

Tags: php, string, split, line

I have a very large string that has a couple "\n" line break per paragraph.

I have 3-4 pages (3-4 fields) that I want to insert the article into, but if it does not fit in the 1st page (1st field), I want to continue the string data into the 2nd page (2nd field).

1st page (1st field) has 14 lines
2nd page - 4th page (1st field - 4th field) has 48 lines each page/field.

I have tried str_split, but it has not work for me :(

Here's a sample:

```
$string = "FIRST PARAGRAPH" .  "\N\N" "2ND PARAGRAPH" . "\N\N" . "AND SOOOO ON... ";

// i want to split this string into 4 sections of fields.
$field1 = (has a max of 14 lines, don't know how many characters tho);

$field2 = (has a max of 48 lines, don't know how many characters too!);

$field3 = (has a max of 48 lines, don't know how many characters too!);

$field4 = (has a max of 48 lines, don't know how many characters too!);
```

this will be filled in to ADOBE PDF's 4 sections/fields using FPDF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find something you can split the string on. If each line is deliminated by \n\n then you could do

```
$lines = explode("\n\n", $string);
```

Then line one would be $lines[0], line two would be $lines[1] and so on. You can then use array_slice() to split the strings up in to the field variables.

Comment: ``$lines = preg_split( '/\R\R/', $string);`` works on both UNIX/WINDOWS line-endings

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure to understand your requirements but a script as the following one should work, except that the result is into an array and not into separate variables.

```
// uncomment the following line to get rid of paragraph breaks;
// $string = strtr($string, array("\n\n","\n")); 
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
$pagelen = array(14,48,48,48);

$result = array();
foreach($pagelen as $cPageLen)
    array_push($result, join("\n",array_splice($lines, 0, $cPageLen)));
```